# SwiftUI ModalView changes paddings for List cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swiftui

Seems like opening ModalView changes horizontal paddings for List cell from `16.0` to `20.0`. Did anybody notice this behavior and find any way to fix it?

Full code of simple example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showModal: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<40) {_ in
            Button(action: {
                self.showModal = true
                print("123")
            }) {
                Text("Hello World")
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
                ModalView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is a modal")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: padding 16]

[image: padding 20]